# iTunes 10: What happened to the checkmarks in lists

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-10

I can't find the checkmarks in the iTunes lists anymore. I have used the rule *is checked* heavily in my smart playlists, but the option has disappeared from the menu.
How can I get the checkmarks back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are still there, however you might have to enable them in the Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's still there - I think it just moved:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can find the check marks in your preview style for that panel:

[image]

Comment: Link only answer is not usefull, could you elaborate?